# Laravel Pennant - store against session? For A/B testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, ab-testing

I want to use Laravel Pennant to implement A/B testing within my application.

I was wondering whether it is possible to store the feature against the current user session to show two different layouts for users that are not authenticated.

Is this possible? If so, would anyone be able to provide an example?

Comment: Yes, you can use Laravel Pennant for A/B testing by storing the feature flag against the current user session, especially for users who are not authenticated.

Comment: Thanks @Saleh7, I don't suppose you could provide an example of how to set this?

Comment: I don't understand this "I was wondering whether it is possible to store the feature against the current user session to show two different layouts for users that are not authenticated." you want to track authenticated users(users with session) or not?

Answer (score 1):

Using a session as a feature flag is pretty straight forward. Just save it to the session in the feature definition, and retrieve it from the session on subsequent calls.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Lottery;
use Laravel\Pennant\Feature;

Feature::define('some-feature-v2', function (string $scope) {
    $session = session();

    if (!is_null($state = $session->get('feature:some-feature-v2'))) {
        return $state;
    }

    $session->put('feature:some-feature-v2', $enabled = Lottery::odds(50 / 100)());

    return $enabled;
});
```

The `$scope` argument is set using the `Feature::for(...)` function, which in this case is the session ID. It is this key that will be saved to the database (or whichever Pennant driver you're using) for quick retrieval of a feature flag.

```php
if (Feature::for(session()->getId())->active('some-feature-v2')) {
    // The feature is enabled.
}
```

Note that using the session is highly transient since it may expire quite soon depending on your settings. Also the same user will experience different things on different devices.

You also might want to use `php artisan pennant:purge` or `php artisan pennant:purge some-feature-v2` after a while since the records in your database may accumulate quite fast if you save everything by a session ID (every private browser is a new session).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've followed along the steps but am getting an error: "Unable to serialize the feature scope to a string. You should implement the FeatureScopeable contract." - do you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue - its not mentioned in Pennants docs. Thanks

Comment: @Wally I made an error in my code; you cannot use `$request` in `Feature::for($request)` because it must be serialized, since Pennant stores the result of the feature flag in the database for quick retrieval. So to fix that, you can scope them based on `session()->getId()` which should be unique for each session as well. Now, the feature value should be properly cached.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help on this issue and adapting the answer with an explainer - its really helpful since the docs do not cover the use case of A/B testing for a user base who do not sign up or have an authenticated accounts (yet). thanks again!

Comment: Yes, sometimes it takes a little diving into the source code to see what actually happens :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with unauthenticated users, you can use Laravel's session to store and retrieve the feature flag state for each user.

Here's a simplified example to illustrate how you could implement this:

Middleware for Session-Based Feature Flags: Create a middleware that checks if a feature flag is set in the user's session. If not, it decides which version of the feature to show (e.g., A or B), stores this choice in the session, and then continues with the request.

1. Implement the Middleware:
   Generate a new middleware:

   php artisan make:middleware FeatureFlagMiddleware

In the handle method of your new middleware, use the session to store or retrieve the user's feature flag state. Here's an example:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FeatureFlagMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if the feature flag is already determined for the session
        if (!$request->session()->has('feature_flag_A_or_B')) {
            // Determine the feature flag for this session, e.g., randomly or based on any other logic
            $featureFlag = rand(0, 1) ? 'A' : 'B';
            
            // Store the determined feature flag in the session
            $request->session()->put('feature_flag_A_or_B', $featureFlag);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register your middleware in the kernel or route.
Use the Feature Flag in Your Controller or View:

In your controller or directly in your view, use the feature flag from the session to determine which layout or content to display. For example:

```
$featureFlag = session('feature_flag_A_or_B');
if ($featureFlag == 'A') {
    // Show layout A
} else {
    // Show layout B
}
```

After that, Register and Apply Your Middleware.

This example is a basic implementation and can be adapted based on your specific needs, such as using more sophisticated logic to assign the feature flag or integrating more directly with Laravel Pennant's features for a more dynamic and configurable approach. Remember, the key here is using the session to persist the user's feature flag state across their interactions with your application without requiring authentication.

Comment: HI thanks for your answer - this is actually the current config that I use to CRUD A/B testing, its a goof solution but the question I had asked was specifically how to deal with SCOPE being set to Session data for Laravel Peannant. If you are able to change your answer to fit that requirement then that would be great - thanks again for taking the time to write your example, its just not on scope of this question.